# Tasmota & momentary switch, I'm looking for the right switch mode that allows me to recognise SINGLE press, DOUBLE press and HOLD

Tags: tasmota

I'm new to TASMOTA and its console but I am looking to use the momentary switch I've connected to my SONOFF MINIR2 to recognise the single press, double press and HOLD so that I can add a rule that perform something once these are recognised. With switchmode set to 5 and SetOption32 to 4s I am able to recognise a TOGGLE and a HOLD, however I'd like to use my switch like if it was a button.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Regards